# Is there no simplified way to load XML data into a W3C Document object in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I've been looking through Spring 4 framework and am surprised that i don't see some form of Spring abstraction to load an XML document into a W3C Document object.

Typical way would be something like:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));
```

I know this isn't complicated, however I've grown accustomed to seeing Spring abstract everything and provide abstractions to a lot of the standard java factories.

I realize I can use Spring Resource to abstract the `new File()`, and even create my own Spring factory beans, but I am surprised that I cannot find any Spring wrappers around the DocumentBuilder/etc.

Am I missing something obvious in the framework?  Even spring-oxm doesn't seem to have anything.

Comment: There's `DocumentLoader`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-objectxml-mapping-example/)

Comment: @CKing Unless I misread the docs for spring-oxm, it is used mainly for marshalling/unmarshalling from Java <-> XML.  I'm actually looking to load into a W3C Document, not unmarshall to a POJO

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks; I saw that too, but almost seems more verbose to need to specify an EntityResolver, and ErrorResolver, etc which you don't need to do with the DocumentBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

Actually spring provides an abstraction : `spring-oxm`

It helps you writing code without coupling it to a specific `Marshaller`.
You won't have more from Spring because it isn't it's responsibility to do so. Spring's role is to help you plugging different technologies together with a layer of abstraction that keeps your code free from specific implementation.

See more : http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html

Comment: From everything I can tell about spring-oxm, it is great for providing abstraction to a Marhsaller/Unmarshaller.  I guess loading to a W3C Document isn't unmarshalling (in the typical sense of the term) to a POJO, so I wasn't able to find anything in spring-oxm to help out.